# execute postgresql schema script Spring DatabasePopulator complaining Unterminated dollar quote started at position

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

in my spring application i create many tables with Entity classes, and it works well. I use Spring with Hibernate, and the DB is PostgreSQL.

then i need some functions, so i prepare an SQL script having the function code in it. the script executes in pgAdmin as well as in netbeans database service sql window.

But it cannot be executed if i want to run the script after hibernate generates all the tables.
for that purpose i created Beans in ApplicationContext.java

```
@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer() {
final DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
initializer.setDataSource(dataSource());
initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator());
return initializer;
}

private DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
final ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
populator.addScript(schemaScript);
return populator;
}
```

the error i receive is

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unterminated dollar quote started at position 122 in SQL CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.populate_raw_data( source character varying, func character varying) RETURNS integer AS $BODY$ DECLARE cnt integer. Expected terminating $$
```

i've read several questions in SO, but nothing is helped so far. the postgresql driver in pom.xml is version 42.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Default statement separator in `ResourceDatabasePopulator` is `;`. So it sends a piece of the script to the server that stops at the first encountered `;`, and the database cannot make sense of it.

Overriding separator helped me to resolve the same error:

```
databasePopulator.setSeparator(ScriptUtils.EOF_STATEMENT_SEPARATOR);
```

Comment: EOF_STATEMENT_SEPARATOR is only useful if the hole script contains just one statement

Comment: Use own custom separator if no out of the box separators fit your needs. For example the default `;` does not suit the case when statements are `CREATE FUNCTION` or alike which may contain `;` as part of the statement itself.